# Require ticked checkbox for php form submission

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I do know php form validation is touched on often here, but I'm a complete php newbie and I'm just sort of hacking away at a php form script I found [here](http://www.freecontactform.com/html_form.php), so I'm not sure how to proceed here with the two things I require.

I would like my form to require that a Terms & Conditions box is checked before it will submit (and if the box is not checked, to return an error message in the way this script processes error messages).

I would also like the fact that the Terms & Conditions box was checked to be emailed to me with the rest of the form data.

The salient bit of the html that I've tried is:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="terms-and-conditions" value="terms-and-conditions" /><label for="terms-and-conditions">I have read the <a href="terms.html">Terms & Conditions</a> *</label></td>
```

The php form with the alterations I've tried is:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "support@xxxxxxx.com";

    $email_subject = "Order Form";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['URL']) ||

        !isset($_POST['date']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comments']) ||

        !isset($_POST['terms-and-conditions'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $URL = $_POST['URL']; // required

    $date = $_POST['date']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // not required

    $terms-and-conditions = $_POST['terms-and-conditions']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }


  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "URL: ".clean_string($URL)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Date: ".clean_string($date)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Terms And Conditions: ".clean_string($terms-and-conditions)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for submitting the order form.


<?php

}

?>
```

With what I've added, the form now throws a 500 Internal Server Error. I was able to successfully add and remove input fields to and from this php form, but I have no idea how to require it to have a checkbox filled in before it will submit (plus have it return the error message if it's not filled in) and have it email me, with the rest of the data, that it has been filled in.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use JavaScript to check if the T&C box was checked, or are you only interested in pure server-side validation? On a side note, you need a corresponding ID attribute when using the for attribute of a label. So with `<label for="terms-and-conditions">` you probably want `<input id="terms-and-conditions" type="checkbox" name="terms-and-conditions" value="terms-and-conditions" />`

Comment: @j08691 I wouldn't mind anything really, just as long as it works and I'm able to implement it! Thanks; will look into your label notes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify the checkbox is 'ticked' (checked) *before* the form is send to the server, you will need some javascript.
A very (very!) crude check would look like

`<form onsubmit="return this.elements['terms-and-conditions'].checked;">`

This will (silently, so without feedback) prevent form submission if the 'terms-and-conditions' checkbox is not in a checked state.
As said, this is a very crude prevention, not at all usable. [Please see this topic for more elaborate checks and solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-to-stop-form-submission)

As to why the server raises an `500 Internal Server Error`:
You cannot have a variable with `-` characters in them, so `$terms-and-conditions` raises the parse error.
Consider using underscores instead, for example `$terms_and_conditions` or [`$termsAndConditions`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)

Comment: Did try changing the hyphens to underscores, but it still throws an error. I will look through the topic you linked. Thank you.